# jQuery JSONP Callback not firing

Tags: jquery

I'm making a cross-domain AJAX request using jQuery but my callback function is not firing (see http://jsfiddle.net/zC8z5/).

```
function jsonpCallback(response){
    $('#code').text(response.data);
}

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert(error);
    },
    success: function() {
        alert("success");                            
    },
    jsonp: false,
    jsonpCallback: 'jsonpCallback'
});
```

As per the docs:

> As of jQuery 1.5, setting the jsonp option to false prevents jQuery
>   from adding the "?callback" string to the URL or attempting to use
>   "=?" for transformation. In this case, you should also explicitly set
>   the jsonpCallback setting. For example, { jsonp: false, jsonpCallback:
>   "callbackName" }

However, if I don't specify a callback and instead just handle the data in the success event it works (see http://jsfiddle.net/2gBRT/).

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert(error);
    },
    success: function(data) { 
        jsonpCallback(data);
    }
});
```

Have I misunderstood how to make JSONP requests with jQuery?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As noted in the docs you excerpted, if the server expects a parameter called `callback`, jQuery is smart enough to fill in the blank for you.  Bitbucket does use this parameter name, so you get a URL like:

```
https://api.bitbucket.org/.../?callback=jquery1234_5678
```

`jquery1234_5678` would actually be an automatically generated function name for your callback. Bitbucket then returns something like:

```
jquery1234_5678({
    "node": "someId",
    "path": "filename",
    "data": "content"
})
```

so the function is called. Also, you can simplify ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SFP7y)) the success part to:

```
success: jsonpCallback
```

If Bitbucket expected a different parameter name, you would use that as the value of jsonp.  So for example, if you passed:

```
jsonp: "functionName"
```

the URL would look something like:

```
https://api.bitbucket.org/.../?functionName=jquery1234_5678
```

but the response would be the same.

You only need `jsonpCallback` if you don't want jQuery to generate the function name.

Comment: Mostly people look at JSONP to get around CORS. And they don't have access to the server. If they did why would the not just enable CORS headers instead of going to the trouble of implementing JSONP callback?