# AJAX Get status was Ok but jsonp callback returns undefined data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am sending an ajax request to retrieve data from salesforce using jsonp but jsonp callback data returns undefined

My ajax request is,

```
$j.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async: this.asyncAjax,
            url: "https://na14.salesforce.com/services/data/v26.0/
                      sobjects/customobject?callback=mycallback",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            data: payload,
            jsonp: false,
            jsonpCallback: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                    alert('Data is '+data);
                    alert('Text status is '+textStatus);
                    alert('jqXHR is '+jqXHR);
            },
            error: (!this.refreshToken || retry ) ? error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                if (jqXHR.status === 401) {
                    that.refreshAccessToken(function(oauthResponse) {
                        that.setSessionToken(oauthResponse.access_token, null,
                        oauthResponse.instance_url);
                        that.ajax(path, callback, error, method, payload, true);
                    },
                    error);
                } else {
                    error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
                }
            },
            dataType: "jsonp",
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                if (that.proxyUrl !== null) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('SalesforceProxy-Endpoint', url);
                }
                xhr.setRequestHeader(that.authzHeader, "OAuth " + that.sessionId);
                xhr.setRequestHeader('X-User-Agent', 'salesforce-toolkit-rest-javascript/' + that.apiVersion);

                if (that.userAgentString !== null) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('User-Agent',that.userAgentString);
                }
            }
        });
```

But, i got my response is,

```
Data is undefined.
Text status is undefined.
jqXhr is undefined.
```

How do i solve this? Is that ajax request in the right format?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate... check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9238504/jquery-jsonp-callback-not-firing ... either use a globally available function named `mycallback` or change the syntax of .ajax() to use jsonp: "callback" (since this parameter seems to be expected by the server accordsing to your example)

Answer (score 0):

You are manually setting the name of the callback parameter sent to the URL, but there is no function called `mycallback`.

You are setting `jsonpCallback` to a function.  jQuery will take the ***return value*** of that function and send it as the `callback` parameter (if you let it send that parameter).

The *correct way* to do JSONP is:

```
$j.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async: this.asyncAjax,
            url: "https://na14.salesforce.com/services/data/v26.0/sobjects/customobject",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            data: payload,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                    alert('Data is '+data);
                    alert('Text status is '+textStatus);
                    alert('jqXHR is '+jqXHR);
            },
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Rocket. Hazmat. Its not working, it executes neither success nor error function. its blank..

Comment: @user1311776: Why are you POSTing data to this page? What are you trying to do? The way JSONP works is by appending a `<script>` tag to the page. I don't think your data is getting POSTed, because that's not how JSONP works.

Comment: @PinoyStackOverflower: This answer is from over a year ago.  You can't POST to a JSONP resource.  I guess I never updated the answer.