# Populate HTML table from AJAX response

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have some data in MySQL database. I want to show that data in html table based on the parameter selected by the user.
Following is the input section (HTML)

```
<form class="form-inline">
    <div class="input-group">
        <div>Enter Person Name</div>
        <input class="form-control" id="tags">
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit">Search</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is the table where I want to populate the data coming from AJAX response.

```
<div class="dataTable_wrapper">
    <table class='table table-striped table-bordered table-hover' id='records_table'>
        <tr class='odd gradeX'>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Group</th>
            <th>Work</th>
            <th>Grade1</th>
            <th>Grade2</th>
            <th>Grade3</th>
            <th>TeacherName</th>
            <th>RollNo</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Now on clicking the 'Search' button, I want to send the name to PHP file, and get the information form database.

for which I have done this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var selText = $('#tags').val();

        if (selText === '') {
            alert("Please select a name!");
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'getData.php',
                jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                jsonp: false,
                data: {
                    q: selText
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                    var trHTML = '';

                    $.each(response, function (i, item) {
                        $.each(item, function (_, o) {
                            trHTML += '<tr><td>' + o.Name +
                                '</td><td>' + o.Group +
                                '</td><td>' + o.Work +
                                '</td><td>' + o.Grade1 +
                                '</td><td>' + o.Grade2 +
                                '</td><td>' + o.Grade3 +
                                '</td><td>' + o.TeacherName +
                                '</td><td>' + o.RollNo. +
                                '</td></tr>';
                        });
                    });
                    $('#records_table').append(trHTML);
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    $("#txtHint").html(e.responseText);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

The PHP code is

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost"; $username = "root"; $password = "21343"; $dbname = "do_demob";
$selectedName = $_GET['q'];
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}   
$sql = "SELECT *** Don't have rights to reveal";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$rows = array();
if($result) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
    }
}else {
    echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysqli_error();
}
$json = json_encode($rows);
echo $json;
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

The AJAX response is

```
[{"Name":"Sagar Mujumbdar","Group":"","TeacherName":"John     Cena","RollNo":"SX51998","Work":"Sales","Grade1":"Good","Grade2":"5","Grade3":"1"}]
```

the Status Code is:200 OK. I also checked in Developer Tools' Network section, the data is coming completely and in correct format. The key names are also correct. 
But unfortunately the data is not being displayed in the table.
Is the reason that because JSON object contain null values it is not displaying?
If not, then what else can be the reason?

Comment: How the response from `ajax` looks like?

Comment: In continuation to @Tushar question, what's your php code that sending the response? If you get `null`s in your response - it might be up to your php code.

Comment: @OfirBaruch I don't think so. He said he is getting data in `response`

Comment: But later on he say `Is the reason that because JSON object contain null values it is not displaying?` - or I misunderstood that sentence.

Comment: is your `response` data really 2 levels deep - `$.each(response, function (i, item) { $.each(item, function (_, o) {`?  typically it would be under the 1st `$.each()`, ie. `item.Name`, `item.Group`, etc.

Comment: @Sean I made the changes as you suggested and still it didn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

1. You have a syntax error right after `RollNo`:

   ```
   '</td><td>' + o.RollNo. +
   ```

   Remove the `.`.
2. In your iteration, you go one element to deep, `o.*` will be undefined, because `o` already is `"Sagar Mujumbdar"`, `""`, etc. One `.each` is enough:

   ```
   $.each(response, function (i, o) {
       trHTML += '<tr><td>' + o.Name +
                 '</td><td>' + o.Group +
                 '</td><td>' + o.Work +
                 '</td><td>' + o.Grade1 +
                 '</td><td>' + o.Grade2 +
                 '</td><td>' + o.Grade3 +
                 '</td><td>' + o.TeacherName +
                 '</td><td>' + o.RollNo. +
                 '</td></tr>';
   });
   ```

I also created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uL45bxn3/) with your AJAX response.

Comment: your code is also giving the response, but in error i.e.  $("#txtHint").html(e.responseText);

Comment: I assumed the function `jsonCallback` to be defined, which I now guess is not the case, right? With JSONP, the function with the name given as `jsonpCallback` will be called instead of `success`, afaik. See [this question & answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9238504/jquery-jsonp-callback-not-firing), the fiddle in the answer is especially helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try following logic. There may some error like braces, and comma because i edited it in here. try the table heading is also in javascript. I done it below. Please check

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnSubmit").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var selText = $('#tags').val();

            if (selText === '') {
                alert("Please select a name!");
            } else {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: 'getData.php',
                    jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    jsonp: false,
                    data: {
                        q: selText
                    },
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert(response);
                        var trHTML = "<table class='table table-striped table-bordered table-hover' id='records_table'>
            <tr class='odd gradeX'>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Group</th>
                <th>Work</th>
                <th>Grade1</th>
                <th>Grade2</th>
                <th>Grade3</th>
                <th>TeacherName</th>
                <th>RollNo</th>
            </tr>";
                    for(var i =0;i < response.length-1;i++)
                      {
                         var o= response[i];

                                trHTML += '<tr><td>' + o.Name +
                                    '</td><td>' + o.Group +
                                    '</td><td>' + o.Work +
                                    '</td><td>' + o.Grade1 +
                                    '</td><td>' + o.Grade2 +
                                    '</td><td>' + o.Grade3 +
                                    '</td><td>' + o.TeacherName +
                                    '</td><td>' + o.RollNo +
                                    '</td></tr>';
                           }
                        trHTML+="</table>" 
                        $('#records_table').append(trHTML);
                    },
                    error: function (e) {
                        $("#txtHint").html(e.responseText);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```