# displaying data from database in jqxDataTable

Tags: php, jquery, jqxgrid

I have a jqxDataTable like so [Check this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0urcb43y/), it is the example from the jqx website

which I am trying to implement and display the data from my database into the jqxDataTable but I have no example running online on how to do that? I am using php in server-side scripting. Is it possible from php? Ajax maybe? Can someone point out how to populate the table from database.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
        var row = {};
        var productindex = Math.floor(Math.random() * productNames.length);
        var price = parseFloat(priceValues[productindex]);
        var quantity = 1 + Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
        row["firstname"] = firstNames[Math.floor(Math.random() * firstNames.length)];
        row["lastname"] = lastNames[Math.floor(Math.random() * lastNames.length)];
        row["productname"] = productNames[productindex];
        row["price"] = price;
        row["quantity"] = quantity;
        row["total"] = price * quantity;
        data[i] = row;
    }
```

This is updating from the hardcoded value.

Comment: Ajax is your best option.  But if you do this on load, I recommend building it from php.

Comment: How can I load it on `load`,can you give me an example.

Comment: Please see [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30183570/populate-html-table-from-ajax-response) to see a full implementation of the flow you wish to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

This is very basic. You need a function to go to your database, then you need to connect to that function. This is in no way complete. You will need further coding.

## PHP

```
function conn(){
$dbhost = 'localhost:3036';
   $dbuser = 'root';
   $dbpass = 'rootpassword';

   $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

   if(! $conn ) {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }

   $sql = 'SELECT emp_id, emp_name, emp_salary FROM employee';
   mysql_select_db('test_db');
   $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

   if(! $retval ) {
      die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
   }

   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
      echo "EMP ID :{$row['emp_id']}  <br> ".
         "EMP NAME : {$row['emp_name']} <br> ".
         "EMP SALARY : {$row['emp_salary']} <br> ".
         "--------------------------------<br>";
   }

   echo "Fetched data successfully\n";

   mysql_close($conn);
}
```

## AJAX

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                action: 'conn',
                somevaluetosend : value,
            },

            success : function(msg){
                console.log(msg); //put this in a function, that will then assign in your table.
            },
            datatype: 'json' //depends on what you get back
        });
```